# Rails 4.0.0 strong parameters don't seem to work as documented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller, strong-parameters

The example used in the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) for strong parameters is:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

However, this doesn't work because require() returns the value of the parameter, not another parameter object that permit() can be called on.

```
$ rails console
1.9.3p286 :005 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new(person: 1, name: "Joe", age: 30)
 => {"person"=>1, "name"=>"Joe", "age"=>30} 
1.9.3p286 :006 > params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for 1:Fixnum
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/jeremyburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jeremyburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jeremyburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Additionally, it seems odd that require can only take 1 parameter. It seems that you should be able to do:

```
params.require(:a, :b).permit(:c, :d)
```

Whereas, what you have to do is:

```
params.require(:a)
params.require(:b)
params.permit(:a, :b, :c, :d)
```

which doesn't seem very DRY - if a parameter is required then it is by definition permitted, surely.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention of `require` is for working with Rails `form_for` objects, whereby the params hash will include the name of the object you're wrapping a form around. So like this:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(person: { name: 'Francesco' }).require(:person)
```

In this case, the `form_for` would have been wrapped around a `Person` object. So the `.require(:person)` will then wrap the resulting hash (`{ name: 'Francesco' }`) up into an `ActionController::Parameters` object which can respond to `.permit`. So your test just wasn't mimicking the expected params use-case.

Also, it makes sense that `require` would only accept one argument since you'd want to setup a unique `<attribute>_params` method per object type since, again, these are meant to be wrappers around a specific object. But, normally you'd only have 1 root object being sent into a form submit, and sub objects within that.